# Use XML Stylesheet to remove elements which match content in another file

Tags: xslt-1.0

I want to transform a xml file like this:

(input.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef>
            <Component Id="c1">
                <File Source="!(PublishDir)\FileA" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="c2">
                <File Source="!(PublishDir)\FileB" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="c3">
                <File Source="!(PublishDir)\FileC" />
            </Component>
            <Component Id="c4">
                <File Source="!(PublishDir)\FileD" />
            </Component>
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup>
            <ComponentRef Id="c1" />
            <ComponentRef Id="c2" />
            <ComponentRef Id="c3" />
            <ComponentRef Id="c4" />
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

This is the simplified output of heat, the wix (Windows Installer XML) harvester. But that shouldn't make a difference.

From the original xml some unwanted files should be removed (including Component and ComponentRef tags). Some of those files are known in advance (FileA) and some file names are in a file like this:

(filelist.xml)

```
<Files>
  <File>FileB</File>
  <File>FileC</File>
</Files>
```

The result should look like this:

(output.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef>
            <Component Id="c4">
                <File Source="!(PublishDir)\FileD" />
            </Component>
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup>
            <ComponentRef Id="c4" />
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Removing a file known in advance is simple, here's what I have so far:

(stylesheet.xsl)

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

  <!-- identity transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <!-- remove files -->
  <xsl:key name="file-search" match="wix:Component[substring(wix:File/@Source, string-length(wix:File/@Source) - 4) = 'FileA']" use="@Id"/>
  <xsl:template match="wix:Component[key('file-search', @Id)]" />
  <xsl:template match="wix:ComponentRef[key('file-search', @Id)]" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But how can the files from "filelist.xml" be reomoved? Here's what I've tried, but that does not work (Variables not allowed in match)

```
<xsl:variable name="filelist" select="document('filelist.xml')"/>
<xsl:key name="file-search" match="wix:Component[contains($filelist, substring-after(wix:File/@Source, '\'))]" use="@Id"/>
```

A XSLT 1.0 solution is preferable, because the tooling supports it, but I could also use a XSLT 2.0 with some additional hookup.

Comment: Do note that the template you have labeled "identity transform" is not. It will discard text nodes, as well as any comments, namespace nodes and processing instructions present in the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main obstacles you face when doing this in XSLT 1.0 are (a) that keys do not work across documents and (b) you cannot use a variable in a match pattern.

Perhaps you could do it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
exclude-result-prefixes="wix">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="component-by-filename" match="wix:Component" use="substring-after(wix:File/@Source, '\')" />

<xsl:variable name="exclude-ids" select="key('component-by-filename', 'FileA')/@Id | key('component-by-filename', document('filelist.xml')/Files/File)/@Id "/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="wix:DirectoryRef | wix:ComponentGroup">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(@Id = $exclude-ids)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Great solution, works as expected and is easy to understand.